# Is ありです a colloquial expression for ありがとう?

Tags: usage

I got this as a reply to a YouTube comment:

> コメント返信ありです！

I understood what the person meant but I'd like to know if ありです is that common and if it can have other meanings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes ありです (or sometimes simply あり) means ありがとう, which is used mainly in busy online chats or games.

I don't recommend using it in real conversatons, though, because it I think would sound geeky.

Answer (score 2):

Also, ありです in normal conversations would mean, that something is there (ある) or that something is possible. (その可能性もありですね）